# How can I run formula on a single selected cell in the sheet using macro

Tags: excel, vba

How can I run formula on a single selected cell in the sheet using macro. I do not want the macro to update all the cells except the cell that is selected. Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop formula calculation with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Now you can calculate your cell:

```
cells(1,1).value = MYFORMULA
```

To restore calculation:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate **only** the cell(s) currently selected, you can use:

```
Selection.Calculate
```

(I assume you have the calculation mode set to "Manual", because if it was set to  "Automatic" then this cell and every other cell would already have been calculated prior to your macro running.)